# Google tag manager Record Where User come from

Tags: google-api, google-tag-manager

I create a custom dimension: `customerId` stores ID of my customers.

I want to track where my customers (defined with `customerId`) come from and date they come to my site (`first time`)

How can i do this?

I segment by: `customerId` and `Source/Medium` but they have multiple session with difference medium, i only want record first time (source acquire user)

Comment: This is off topic as it is not related to programming, but you can post to Webmasters where it is more suitable. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use user type in Google Analytics to see if a user with customerId is new. This can be done with custom report or with API. 
Also you can use other custom dimension to track date of first visit (for example, if GA cookie doesn't exist, than visit is first).